# not getting up vs haven't got up isn’t apologising vs hasn’t apologised

Tags: sentence-construction

Are all sentences are correct? Is it possible to use these actions with Present Continuous?

> I am not getting up yet.
>
> I haven't got up yet.
>
> He isn’t apologising yet.
>
> He hasn’t apologised yet.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet normally goes with the present perfect so you can't generally use it with the present continuous.  He isn't apologising yet is definitely wrong. The confusion with I'm not getting up yet lies in the fact that yet is used in substitution of now and this is acceptable for informal speech.